# create and emit gtk signal

Tags: c, signals, gtk

I am trying to create and emit a GTK signal:

```
g_signal_new("child-finished",
    G_TYPE_OBJECT,
    G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,
    0,
    NULL, NULL,
    NULL,           // *** I think this is where I need to change it
    G_TYPE_NONE, 0);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(myWindow), "child-finished", G_CALLBACK(MyCallback), NULL);
```

Here is my code that emits the signal:

```
gtk_signal_emit_by_name(referenceToMyWindow, "child-finished");
```

And here is my code that handles the signal:

```
void MyCallback(GtkWidget *w, GdkEvent *e)
{
    // handler code here
}
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

> GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g`_closure_`invoke: assertion `closure->marshal || closure->meta_marshal' failed

I know it has something to do with passing a marshaller to the `g_signal_new` function, but I don't know what a marshaller is, I can't understand [the documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/gobject-Closures.html#GClosureMarshal), and the examples online are few and far between.  How do I declare and connect my own signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GObject library provides some [builtin marshallers](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/struct.CClosure.html), so your code should probably be:

```
g_signal_new("child-finished",
             G_TYPE_OBJECT, G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,
             0, NULL, NULL,
             g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__POINTER,
             G_TYPE_NONE, 1, G_TYPE_POINTER);
```

or, if you want type checking:

```
g_signal_new("child-finished",
             G_TYPE_OBJECT, G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,
             0, NULL, NULL,
             g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__BOXED,
             G_TYPE_NONE, 1, GDK_TYPE_EVENT);
```

The parameters of the signal handler **must** be present (the object itsself is implied), so be sure to specify a pointer (as in the first example) or a boxed type (as in the second example).

If the marshaller you need is not present in the builtins ones, you could use the [glib-genmarshal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/glib-genmarshal.1.html) utility or directly code it by yourself (it is quite trivial, just checkout the output of glib-genmarshal).

Comment: Just a correction of what said above: GBoxed types do not have type checking, they are only wrappers for C structs with no type information. The real difference between G_TYPE_POINTER vs G_TYPE_BOXED is that in the latter a _copy_ of the GdkEvent structure is used. If event is not modified this does not make any difference but if you need to modify it, use G_TYPE_POINTER.