# GLib/GObject intercept errors / structure code for testing, reporting or debugging

Tags: c, unix, testing, process, glib

### Situation:

I am working on upgrading some code at my work place. The code is for a process that is based off of GMime. We currently use GMime 2.2 and I recently upgraded our code to use GMime 2.4. The proces runs just fine and doesn't crash, but I get a

`GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed`

every now and then when the program is running.

There are times that calls to g_object_unref fails and crashes my program. I'm trying to debug this, but unfortunately the person who made this program didn't add any testing or debugging features.

I know and understand how important embedding debugging information or setting up a testing framework is, when you have to go back into old code. I know how to set this up in pure C or pure C++, but as soon as other libararies get tossed in it becomes really difficult.

### My problem is:

How how do I effectively setup debug code and/or a testing system with a program that relies on GLib or GObject?

### My questions are:

1. How can I tell what's happening in the code? Should I be listening for "signals"? How do I setup those signals?
2. Functions like `g_object_unref` return `void`. That being the case how do I output debugging information related to these functions?
3. Does a GObject have a "property/class member", I don't know the proper term for this in relation to GLib, that has error information embedded in it?
4. (Related, but slightly off topic) Libraries like GLib and node.js ecetera have "extensive" documentation that amounts to:

   `function doSomethingThatShouldBeUsefulAndUnderstoodByAnyoneWhoReadsThis(WYSIWYG, FIY, BYOF, X, Y, Z) // this function does something that should be usefull and understood by anyone who reads the function this does something and can be called`

   How does one has a lot of programming experience (with languages in their pure form), go about making heads or tails of the library when most tutorials refer you back to the documents or are the documents themselves?
5. Is there a recommended tutorial for this?

### Sites I have looked at:

- http://arunchaganty.wordpress.com/2008/05/18/i-am-a-gobject/
- [create and emit gtk signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557025/create-and-emit-gtk-signal)
- https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-running.html
- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/a2901.html
- https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html

Any and all comments, questions and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I'm currently looking at the [Maman Tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/howto-signals.html), it looks promising. I'll see where it gets me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I know of to debug issues like this is to run the program under a debugger and break on g_logv (that error message was printed with g_logv) and when the debugger catches a call to g_logv, you can get a backtrace to see where in your program you are.

Usually these types of errors happen when a programmer tries to call g_object_unref() on a NULL pointer.

That said, is there a reason you only upgraded to GMime 2.4 instead of GMime 2.6? 2.6 has been out for several years now and is the series that is best maintained.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I really appreciate your feedback.
I'm going to go ahead and give the g_logv debugging a try and see what I get.  
There are two reasons that I'm upgrading to GMime 2.4 instead of 2.6.  
1) My boss said so...  
2) I work in Japan and they wanted me to upgrade to 2.4 for the "time being"  


That's about it. I agree with you on 2.6 and I have voiced my opinion to my boss.    


Q: Do you have any recommendations on debuggers that I could use from the UNIX command line?

Comment: The one I use is gdb (which is the most commonly used debugger on Linux and other UNIX systems)

Comment: Got it! I'll update you on my progress later and I'll be sure to get back to this thread.

Comment: I looked up a tutorial for gdb and it will make it much easier for me to fix this program.

Comment: Good luck! For debugging on Linux, gdb is the only real option for debugging native code.